# Which android API calls need these permission?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm trying to figure out which android API calls need these permissions:

- android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST
- android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
- android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC
- android.permission.GET_TOP_ACTIVITY_INFO

I read the descriptions on the Android developer website, but I found no way to perform the operations that these permissions allow.

EDIT after HexAndBugs answer: I know these permission are not intended for third-party application, but I'd like to use them in a experimental environment, playing the role of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't intended to be used in your apps (unless you are a device manufacturer), so you won't find things that need them in the API.  Note that they all say `Not for use by third-party applications`.  See, for example, [DEVICE_POWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER)

Comment: I know that, but I'd like to use them in a monitoring in-lab experiment... thus, I'm playing the role of manufacturer.

Comment: So the answer to your question is there are no API calls that need these permissions. However, if you still want to access functionality in the OS that uses these permissions you'll have to bypass the API and either build a custom version of Android and modify the code so you can call the functionality or you'll have to see if you can access the functionality using reflection.

Comment: I don't know why you can't find them. Search the Android source code for the permissions, and then you'll see that `HARDWARE_TEST`, for example, is used in `com.android.server.lights.LightsService`. Then you just need to modify your custom version of the Android source to call it, or access it via reflection as I mentioned previously, because you can't call them directly as they are not part of the API. See [LightsService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r3.1/services/java/com/android/server/LightsService.java)

Answer (score 0):

Although these settings are not for usual app but if you have a rooted device and you need to control, lets say hardware test then you would have to add it to your apps permisson and override the ususal CET testing pannel

But FYI it can brick the phone or device if you tweaksomething wrong so beaware;

i personally have used couple of these permisson for e.g getTop Activity info to monitor that my app is always on foreground